# Unable to access cartridge in Grohe bathroom monobloc mixer tap

Tags: faucet, cartridge, leaking

Morning all,

My Grohe bathroom tap (Allure Brilliant model) is leaking. In trying to get to the internal cartridge to replace it, Ive tried to get to the set screw (please see images below) using allen keys, but its not taking at all.

I'm thinking the allen key groove may be worn down hence why its not taking.

Any advice would be much appreciated in how I can get the set screw out.

Good day all

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying standard and metric sizes?  Is the shape matching, is it hex(allen) or something like torx?

Comment: Try using your phone with flash on to take a few photos to see what sort of screw it is.  Or visit a store and check it there.

Comment: Cheers Rohit, i'll visit a store to check it out...great advice: )

Answer (score 1):

Get a mirror and a bright flashlight and see what you're actually dealing with. Those allen screws are usually heat treated and it's hard to wear down the groove unless you're using the wrong size.

Comment: Cheers Jack, tried this but reflected light only goes so far down and hard to see what I am dealing with.